# Number of ways of adding n distinct positive integers, in particular n = 4

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ distinct positive integers, how many ways are there of summing them?  Order matters.
This question specifically asks for the case where n = 4.

I will describe the cases for n = 2 and n = 3 as examples.

Let $a =$ first number

Let $b =$ second number

Let $c =$ third number

Let $d =$ fourth number

(These are used for up to $n = 4$)

---

Example: Case $n = 2$

(Picture these arranged vertically, as in elementary arithmetic.)

$a + b$

$b + a$

So, there are a total of $2$ ways for $2$ distinct positive integers being added.

---

Example: Case $n = 3$

---

$ a + b + c$

(Picture this arranged vertically, as well as the other subcases.)  They are added all at once here.
There are $6$ orderings here, as there are that number of permutations.

---

$(a + b) + c $

Add two of them first, get the sum, then add that sum to the remaining third number $c$.
There are $2$ choices out of $3$ for the first two numbers, and then there is just the
$1$ choice for the remaining number.  The variables can be put in two orders inside
the parentheses for a subtotal of $6$ orderings.

---

$a + (b + c)$

Place the first number at the top $a$.  Sum the other two numbers, and place their sum beneath
the first number. Add those results.  Like the last similar subcase, there are a subtotal of $6$ orderings.

---

So, there are a total of 18 ways for $3$ distinct positive integers being added.

---

Question:

In like manner, how many total ways are there of summing $4$ distinct positive integers?

Comment: Ramanujan Famous Partition function and this was even in that moive Man Who Knew Infinity

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas Are you sure it is right? Can you give me a convicing argument so that I could believe in that, because I see something different, but also interesting here?

Comment: It would help if you spent some more effort into formalizing these conditions for brackets.

Comment: Oh Sorry I mis read the question,  I read the question as How many partition of the integer n exist considered in full length

Comment: Now, I read it so let me answer.

Comment: There are $2^{n}-1$ ways of choosing n integers. Now we have weights for each such and weight for I integers is $k!$ so answer should be $\sum k! {n\choose k}$ k>0 and less than equals ro n

Comment: @donaastor is it correct?

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas hahaha I am fixing my answer literally 20 times, I need time to check confidently. Can you check mine?

Comment: Let me see, 1,2 then 1,2,1+2,2+1.

Comment: 1,2,3 then 1,2,3 , 1+2 ,1+3,2+3 ,1+2+3 so the answer for 3 is 1x3+2x3+6×1=15

Comment: It's 15 for 3 answer in general for n is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k! {n\choose k}$

Comment: Note that you can just work out the possibilities for operands in one order, then multiply by the factorial of the number of operands.

Comment: Okay I understand The question wrong, I am trying now wait

Comment: @Safal Das Biswas -- I changed my mind about posting those ways for n = 3, because it would take a long time to type out, for one thing.

Comment: Okay no problem, I understand op's way of thinking so no problem , I understand it what op trying to say.

Comment: @Safal Das Biswas -- I will write out hints for the case n = 4 in the Answer section.  Then I will leave to go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

In the first variant, it's 264; here is how you can derive the formula:

If the order of operands is different, then by your definition they must be different ways. So we can group the ways you're trying to count into $n!$ collections (for $n$ numbers). Then we just need to count the ways of placing these brackets. Now formalizing your definition for brackets is tricky, so let me drop the bomb now. Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to place brackets around $n$ operands with the restriction that there must be at least one bracket pair and that there is no bracket pair that embraces $n$ operands or $1$ operand and that there are no duplicate pairs. We are looking for $f(n)+1$ with this definition because we want to count the case with no brackets. Since now there is at least one bracket pair, let's take the one whose right bracket is the last bracket in the whole expression. Call that bracket pair $X$. From the left bracket of $X$ to the left end of the expression let's say there are $a$ operands. From the right bracket of $X$ to the right end of the expression let's say there are $b$ operands. We have the restrictions:
$0<a+b<n-1$,
$a\ge 0$ and
$b\ge 0$.
The number of ways to further pick brackets left to the $X$ is $2(f(a)+1)$ if $a\ge2$ (it can be no brackets and there can be or not be a bracket embracing all $a$ operands if $a\ge2$) or $1$ otherwise, the number of ways to further pick brackets right to the $X$ is $1$ (by the definition of $X$) and the number of ways to further pick brackets inside $X$ is $f(n-a-b)+1$ (we can pick no brackets, but we can't embrace all the operands because it is exactly $X$ already). This gives the recursion formula:
$f(n)=\sum_{0<a+b<n-1,a\ge2}2(f(a)+1)(f(n-a-b)+1)+\sum_{0<a+b<n-1,a<2}(f(n-a-b)+1).$
It can be derived that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=0$ because the sum is empty in these cases. Now I belive the topic of actually solving this recursion is a separate one; you can use it to find $f(4)$ and then $(f(4)+1)\cdot4!$ is the result you want. A simplified recursive formula for $g(n)=f(n)+1$ is:
$$g(n)=1+2\sum_{s=1}^{n-2}\bigg(\sum_{a=1}^s g(a)\bigg)g(n-s)$$
And $g(n)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the series expansion of the function
$$\frac{1+x-\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}{4}$$
The first 5 elements of this sequence (multiplied by $n!$) are: $1,2,18,264,5400$.

---

In the second variant, it's 288. Here is how you can derive the formula:

In every step you are taking $k\ge2$ operands and adding them in one of $k!$ possible ways. Different sequence of steps is the definition of different ways of adding, as given by the OP in one of his understandings. Starting with $n$ operands and taking $k$ operands in the first step we are left with $n-k+1$ operands. This gives the immediate recursion formula:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n k!\binom{n}{k}f(n-k+1),\forall n\ge2.$$
We can substitute $g(k)=\frac{f(k)}{(k-1)!}$ and divide both sides with $(n-1)!$ to get
$$g(n)=n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}g(k),\forall n\ge2,$$
and since $f(1)$ was equal to $1$ by special case, we have $g(1)=\frac{1}{0!}=1$ too. The recursion gives $g(2)=2$. For $n\ge3$ we can significantly simplify this recursion:
$$g(n)=n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}g(k)=n\bigg(g(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}g(k)\bigg)=n\bigg((n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}g(k)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}g(k)\bigg)=$$
$$=n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}g(k)=\frac{n^2}{n-1}g(n-1).$$
Applying this result $n-2$ times gives
$$\forall n\ge3:g(n)=g(2)\prod_{k=3}^{n}\frac{k^2}{k-1}=g(2)\frac{\big(\frac{n!}{2}\big)^2}{(n-1)!}=\frac{n\cdot n!}{2}.$$
We can check that this formula holds for $n=2$ too: $g(2)=2=\frac{2\cdot2!}{2}$. So, for $n\ge2$ we have
$$f(n)=g(n)(n-1)!=\frac{(n!)^2}{2}.$$
The first five elements of this sequence are $1,2,18,288,7200$.

---

EDIT: Notice how the most popular HDD rpms are exactly the fifth elements of these sequences, 5400rpm and 7200rpm!